# mysqli statement does not work under php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There's a bit problem for mysqli select statement as I did a select statement which actually counts the number of results. But it does not return the value I want but instead it returns none. Need help guys. I did this select statement as a function using mysqli and php

```
function count_result($data){
    global $con;
    $sql    = "SELECT count(user_id) as userssss from credentials where user_id = '$data'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('userssss');
    echo "string</br>";
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['userssss']."asdasd</br>";
    die("userssss");
    $return = $row['user'];

    return $return;
}
```

**result**

string
asdasd
userssss

It should show the result before asdasd

Comment: Check the result of `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Use prepared statements,

Comment: `user` is a reserved word

Comment: I dont want to use prepared statement. Just need a simple yet understandable code. I was checking it and I think there's a problem in mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_assoc. Any suggestion aside from the prepared statement and even if I use other words aside from user it still doe not return the expected output.

Comment: use `or die()` statement after `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` to get error and `user` is a keyword so enclose it with `

Comment: Is your column name `usersss` as you have used `$row['userssss']`; check it. It shoul be $row['users'] or `$row['user]` @NewbieProggie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Silly of me.

Instead of using assoc, one must use array

```
function count_result($data){
    global $con;
    $sql    = "SELECT count(user_id) as userssss from credentials where user_id = '$data'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('userssss');
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $return = $row['user'];

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: This was also the mistake and I guess was the main issue `$row['usersss']` and you have already replaced that as well with `$row['user']`

Answer (score 0):

add global $con;

```
function count_result($data){
    global $con;
    $sql    = "SELECT count(user_id) as user from credentials where user_id = '$data'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['user'][0]."asdasd";
    die();
    $return = $row['user'][0];

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake in your code :

```
function count_result($data){
    global $con;
    $sql    = "SELECT count(user_id) as userssss from credentials where user_id = '$data'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('userssss');
    echo "string</br>";
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['user']."asdasd</br>"; // did changes on this line 
    die("userssss");
    $return = $row['user'];

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Please do not repost my answer just to gain points. It was clear that you are doing that.

Comment: @NewbieProggie, I also mentioned the issue in your code, you need to check the comments that I mentioned in your answer. Because of that mistake I posted new answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to count everything meaning rows matched where clause. Also try to adopt prepared statements. Bellow code works.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function count_result($data){
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'database';
$host = 'hostname';
$port = 3306;

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL server */

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if($stmt = $link -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE ID= ?")) 
    {
    /* Bind parameters, s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("i", $data);
    $stmt -> execute();

    /* Bind results */
    $stmt -> bind_result($testfield1);

    /* Fetch the value */
    $stmt -> fetch();
    $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute SQL. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

/* Close statement */
$stmt -> close();
echo '# rows: '. $numberofrows . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Count = '. $testfield1 ;

}

count_result(24);
?>
```